# Biometric Windows Logon with Local SQL Database storing fingerprints

Tags: sql-server, validation, windows-authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

I have a biometric scanner `U.are.U  4500` from digital persona.

A locally hosted SQL Express database is storing fingerprints on a pc, Windows has the ability to use the device directly for logging into windows by only using the WBF (Windows Biometrics Foundation) setup. I cannot seem to find any way to point the authentication or validation to get the fingerprints from the local Database.

Is it possible to point windows to the local db for fingerprint validation without any 3rd party software? if not, is there software which will allow this kind of behaviour?